# Expecting statement error from php loop using ACF plugin

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I feel like I've gone over my php loop structure multiple times but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The file is counted as invalid by PHPstorm and won't run properly. Here's the code:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$initialCardLoad = 5;
$loopLazyLoad = 0;
$galleryType = get_field('gallery_type'); ?>


    <section class="grid-content">
        <div class="gridGallery <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

            <?php


            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
            if (have_rows('card')) {

            // loop through the rows of data
            while (have_rows('card')) : the_row();
            $loopLazyLoad++; // iterate on loop each time you loop through
            // display a sub field value inside a card

            //VARIABLES//
            $title = get_sub_field('card_title');
            $childImage = get_sub_field('card_picture');
            $file = get_sub_field('card_video');
            $video = $file['url'];
            $videoTitle = get_sub_field('card_video_title');
            $cardLink = get_sub_field('card_link');
            $cardEmbed = get_sub_field('card_embed');

            if ($loopLazyLoad > $initialCardLoad) {

            if ($cardEmbed) { ?>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/jyEGGG/"
                   href="javascript:;">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                </a>
                <!-- end of iframe If statement --> <?php
                }

                elseif ($childImage) { ?>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $title ?>"
                       href="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['large'];//big one here ?>">
                        <img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                    </a>
                    <!-- End of image if statement --> <?php
                    }



                    elseif ($video) { ?>
                    <div class="grid-item">

                        <a data-fancybox data-src="#<?php echo $videoTitle ?>" href="javascript:;">
                            <video class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted>
                                <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </a>

                        <video style="display: none;" class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted
                               id="<?php echo $videoTitle ?>">
                            <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <!-- end of Video If statement -->
                        <?php
                        } ?>
                    </div> <?php //end of grid item div

                    } // End of if lazy load iter check

                    else { // this is where initial load begins

                    if ($cardEmbed) { ?>
                    <div class="grid-item">
                        <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe"
                           data-src="http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/jyEGGG/" href="javascript:;">
                            <img class="" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                        </a>
                        <!-- end of iframe If statement --> <?php
                        }



                        elseif ($childImage){ ?>
                        <div class="grid-item">
                            <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $title ?>"
                               href="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['large'];//big one here
                               ?>">
                                <img class="" src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                            </a>
                            <!--end of Image IF statement --> <?php
                            }


                            elseif ($video){ ?>
                            <div class="grid-item">

                                <a data-fancybox data-src="#<?php echo $videoTitle ?>" href="javascript:;">
                                    <video class="gallery-video" loop autoplay muted>
                                        <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                    </video>
                                </a>

                                <video style="display: none;" class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted
                                       id="<?php echo $videoTitle ?>">
                                    <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                                <!-- end of Video If statement --> <?php
                                } ?>

                            </div> <!-- end of grid item div -->

                            <!--end of initial card load of loop-->


                            <?php } //end of else for the initial load
///////////// The above curly bracket is where the problem appears ^^^^^^

                            else {
                                ?> <p>no rows found</p>


                            <?php } //end of else
                            endwhile; ////end of while statement that loops for as long as rows have data
                            } //end of top level if statement that checks if rows have data ?>


                </div>

    </section>

    <script>
        domReady(function () {
            var macy_instance = Macy.init({
                container: '.<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>',
                trueOrder: false,
                waitForImages: true,
                debug: false,
                margin: 0,
                columns: 5,
                breakAt: {
                    1200: 4,
                    940: 3,
                    520: 1
                }
            });


            macy_instance.runOnImageLoad(function () {
                macy_instance.recalculate(true);
            }, true);

        });

    </script>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Share the actual error.

Comment: I've added a comment to the the code so you can see where the error is showing up. But the actual error is just "expecting statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `The above curly bracket is where the problem appears` you had second `else` statement, the first `else` without `if` statement is near `this is where initial load begins` you missed the logic.

I cleaned up your code a bit and corrected the error, in the future pay attention to not repeat your code. In each statement you had opening div with the same class name, I moved them before the conditions.

```
<?php

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$initialCardLoad = 5;
$loopLazyLoad    = 0;
$galleryType     = get_field( 'gallery_type' ); ?>

<section class="grid-content">
    <div class="gridGallery <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

        <?php
        // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if ( have_rows( 'card' ) ) {

            // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows( 'card' ) ) :

                the_row();
                $loopLazyLoad ++; // iterate on loop each time you loop through
                // display a sub field value inside a card

                //VARIABLES//
                $title      = get_sub_field( 'card_title' );
                $childImage = get_sub_field( 'card_picture' );
                $file       = get_sub_field( 'card_video' );
                $video      = $file['url'];
                $videoTitle = get_sub_field( 'card_video_title' );
                $cardLink   = get_sub_field( 'card_link' );
                $cardEmbed  = get_sub_field( 'card_embed' );

                if ( $loopLazyLoad > $initialCardLoad ) {

                    ?> <div class="grid-item"> <?php

                    if ( $cardEmbed ) { ?>
                            <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/jyEGGG/"
                               href="javascript:;">
                                <img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                            </a>
                            <!-- end of iframe If statement --> <?php

                    }  else if ( $childImage ) { ?>
                            <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $title ?>"
                               href="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['large'];//big one here ?>">
                                <img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                            </a>
                        <!-- End of image if statement --> <?php

                    } else if ( $video ) { ?>
                            <a data-fancybox data-src="#<?php echo $videoTitle ?>" href="javascript:;">
                                <video class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted>
                                    <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </a>

                            <video style="display: none;" class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted
                                   id="<?php echo $videoTitle ?>">
                                <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                            <!-- end of Video If statement --> <?php
                    } ?>

                    </div> <?php //end of grid item div

                    // End of if lazy load iter check
                    // this is where initial load begins
                    // HERE PUT YOUR LOGIC
                } else if (true) { 

                    ?> <div class="grid-item"> <?php

                    if ( $cardEmbed ) { ?>
                        <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe"
                           data-src="http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/jyEGGG/" href="javascript:;">
                            <img class="" data-src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                        </a>
                        <!-- end of iframe If statement --> <?php

                    } else if ( $childImage ){ ?>
                        <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $title ?>"
                           href="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['large'];//big one here
                           ?>">
                            <img class="" src="<?php echo $childImage['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
                        </a>
                        <!--end of Image IF statement --> <?php

                    } else if ( $video ){ ?>
                        <a data-fancybox data-src="#<?php echo $videoTitle ?>" href="javascript:;">
                            <video class="gallery-video" loop autoplay muted>
                                <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </a>

                        <video style="display: none;" class="gallery-video lazy" loop autoplay muted
                               id="<?php echo $videoTitle ?>">
                            <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                            <!-- end of Video If statement --> <?php
                    } ?>

                    </div> <!-- end of grid item div -->
                    <!--end of initial card load of loop-->  <?php

                    //end of else for the initial load
                } else {
                    ?> <p>no rows found</p> <?php

                } //end of else

            endwhile; ////end of while statement that loops for as long as rows have data
                /// 
        } //end of top level if statement that checks if rows have data ?>


    </div>

</section>

<script>
    domReady( function () {
        var macy_instance = Macy.init( {
            container: '.<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>',
            trueOrder: false,
            waitForImages: true,
            debug: false,
            margin: 0,
            columns: 5,
            breakAt: {
                1200: 4,
                940: 3,
                520: 1
            }
        } );


        macy_instance.runOnImageLoad( function () {
            macy_instance.recalculate( true );
        }, true );

    } );

</script>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I can see where I need to not repeat stuff, as you pointed out, but the second else statement is inside the top level if statement.

Comment: If the second `else` is for the `if ( have_rows( 'card' ) ) {` condition close the `while` loop. The `no rows found` is inside `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, excellent thank you. I added an endwhile inside the top level if check and added an empty else to pair with it. Everything is looking good now. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem please remember to mark it as accepted. Thank you.